# Firebase: a way from insecure rules to a strong security level

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

My realtime database consist of two tables (Users and Conversations). The database stores chat messages and users. All of the conversations are between two people.

Database structure:

```
**Users**

- AliceID 
    - Credentials 
        - Email (*alice@mail.com*) 
        - Name (*Alice*) 
        - ProfilePictuteLink (*https ...*) 

    - MyConversations 
        - interlocutorID (*BobID*) 
            - ConversationID (*AliceBobConvID*) 

- BobID  
    - Credentials 
        - Email (*bob@mail.com*) 
        - Name (*Bob*) 
        - ProfilePictuteLink (*https ...*) 

    - MyConversations 
        - interlocutorID (*AliceID*) 
            - ConversationID (*AliceBobConvID*) 


**Conversations**

- IDofConversation (*AliceBobConvID*) 
    - messageID (*1*) 
        - Content: “Hi, Alice!” 
        - fromID: “BobID” 
        - isRead: true 
        - Timestamp: 1524636221 
        - toID: “AliceID” 
        - Type: “text” 

    - messageID (*2*) 
        - Content: “Hi, Bob!” 
        - fromID: “AliceID” 
        - isRead: true 
        - Timestamp: 1524636321 
        - toID: “BobID” 
        - Type: “text”
```

Currently I am using the following insecure rules

```
{
  "rules": {

    "users" : {
        ".read" : "auth != null",
       ".write" : "auth != null"  
    },

    "conversations" : {
        ".read" : "auth != null",
        ".write" : "auth != null" 
      }
  }
}
```

**Question**: 
Is it possible to write strong security rules for the current database structure? If so, then please suggest security rules to achieve strong security level for the database. If not, then please suggest a database structure that allows to create strong security rules in painless way.

**Some requirements:**

1. An user should be able to read/write his own credentials only.
2. An user should be able to read/write his own "MyConversations" only.
3. An user should be able to delete a conversation with his interlocutor.
4. It should be possible to add a new user to Users.
5. An user should be able to create a new record within "Conversations" as soon as the user wrote the first message to another user.

I am using Facebook authentication.

Comment: The first place to go to get help with per-user security rules would be the documentation.  You should be able to use this to make an initial attempt at writing security rules that satisfy your requirements: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security

Comment: At least show some effort of your research instead of puttingall your requirements to stackoverflow, the community is willing to help but won't spoon-feeding.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to write strong security rules for the current database
>   structure?

**Yes**

> If so, then please suggest security rules to achieve strong security
>   level for the database.

Usually, for your case, we implement user association security rules.  Which means for every chat (IDofConversation) will have userId assigned.  You could add a special array into your IDofConversation to keep track the userId assigned.  Your security rule will be used to check whether the user visit is assigned.  For more details on how to structure the database security rule can be found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security)